# "on lui approché par" vs "on est lui approché par"

Tags: grammaire, accord

Pouvez-vous m'aider à corriger ma deuxième phrase ?

> Pour le premier terme on peut utiliser l'approximation classique :
>    (equation)
>
> Pour le second terme, on lui approché par :

Ou bien dit-on

> Pour le second terme, on est lui approché par :

Comment: `on lui approché par` et `on est lui approché par` sont incorrects tous les deux. Pourrais-tu ajouter un peu de contexte, ou une traduction en anglais ou dans ta langue maternelle de ce que tu veux exprimer?

Comment: jai le remplacé par on l'approche par : le contexte c'est que je veux dire que intégrale est approché par :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aucune des deux propostions n'est correcte.

Si c'est dans un contexte mathématique (ou scientifique en général), tu pourrais utiliser les expressions suivantes:

> Pour le second terme, on l'approxime en:
>
> Le second terme peut être approximé en:
>
> Le second terme s'approxime en:
>
> Le second terme s'approche en:

Comment: oui cest dans un context mathematique, merci